# CSS: why a gap appears between the td and the div?

Tags: html, css

In a table I'm making, whenever a cell has just a bit of content, a gap appears between the td and the div - it looks normal, though, when there a lot of things inside. This looks weird. Can someone help me remove it?

[image: Look this image]

html:

```
<td cod='[@cod]'>
<div class="headler">
    [@inicio] - [@fim]
</div>
<div class="valores_resultados">

    <div class="disciplina" cod="[@cod_disciplina]">
        [@disciplina]
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="professor" cod="[@cod_prof]">
        [@professor]
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 10px;;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}

tr, td, th { 
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    box-shadow:         3px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);

}

td:hover {
    border: rgb(80, 0, 0) solid 1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 0px rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 2px 0px 0px rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.45);
    box-shadow:         3px 2px 0px 0px rgba(80, 0, 0, 0.45);
}

.headler {
    background-color: rgb(145, 0, 0);
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 4% 0%; 
    margin: 0;
}

.valores_resultados{
    min-height: 60px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.disciplina {
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.professor {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML of your table, not whatever templating language that is.

Comment: the generated html will be far more useful, and make sure it's ALL of the html. you're missing all the `<table><tr>` stuff... Plus, your `disciplina` has a `margin-top: 3%`. since that's a RELATIVE measurement, the more content you have, the bigger the margin will be.

Comment: border-spacing: 10px;; One ; to many :)

Comment: I didn't post the whole table because it has more than 72000 characters, but if you really need to see it, http://textuploader.com/5p3u1. About the margin-top, I defined it to 0 and it stayed the same...

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Not work, I'm talking about a gap between the td and the div and no between td's.

Comment: This will remove all gaps in the table. This worked for me on jsfiddle but I have already closed it. Will add the URL next time

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
tr, td, th {vertical-align:top;}
```